# Android google maps v2 make marker moving along predefined gps coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I want to simulate moving object on ANDROID google map. It is basically something like this http://mypersonalsoft.blogspot.com/2012/02/simulating-moving-targets-in-google.html
The marker will move along a set of gps coordinates. From start to end.

I have a long list of gps position. How can I use these positions to move a marker on google map?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code its a modified code from google maps demo app:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;    
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    int i=0,j=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = fm.getMap();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(77,77);



        Marker mrk=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng)
        .title("Rohit")
        .draggable(true)
        .snippet("Delivery Boy")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

        mrk.remove();

        animateMarker(mrk,mrk.isVisible());

    }

    public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final boolean hideMarker) {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final double [] lnglist={75.123445,71.290909,72,73,74,75,77,78,79,82};
        final double [] latlist={71.232334,74.898899,63,64,65,66,64,62,63,63};

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                double lng = lnglist[i++];
                double lat = latlist[j++];

                Marker mrk=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                .title("Rohit")
                .draggable(true)
                .snippet("Delivery Boy")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 5)); 

                for(int k=0;k<200000000;k++);

                if(i>=9)
                {
                    i=0;
                    j=0;

                }
                else{


                    mrk.remove();
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 0);

                }

            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: ok Ive tried this. but to no avail. can you explain more on this. how to call animateMarker from `onCreate()`? what is the difference between `LatLng toPosition` and  `double [] lnglist={PUT YOUR LIST HERE}; double [] latlist={PUT YOUR LIST HERE};`

Comment: Sorry man did'nt test the last code and hence it did'nt work. This is the tested code it works!..Hope this solves your problem

Comment: thank you very much it works well but maps will lag if use many points. at the time of testing, I used 100 points and the map lags like hell. Do you have a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by lags like hell?? are you referring to the time taken to move between two points?

Comment: not the time taken as defined in the code. it is the google map itself lagging

Comment: nope. just that and I added 100 of lats and longs. Is this code practical with thousands of latlong?

Comment: if you are trying to move the marker from one coordinate to other (like in a gps nav software) this isn't the code for you

Comment: Do you have any recommendation on how to achieve that?how to simulate moving objects on a map using predefined coordinates?

Comment: actually, I don't want to simulate it like GPS, i just want to receive data from mysql and plot it on the graph so that it looks like an object is moving